# How do I properly escape international characters in XML with encoding UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, xml, utf-8

Currently I have Javascript generating XML with an encoding set to UTF-8, and we've run into a situation where we occasionally have some international characters present in the XML. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
      <comments><![CDATA[Hola. Mi nombre es Pat. ¿Cómo puedo ayudarle?]]></comments>
</example>
```

Leaving the international characters like this gives us an encoding error when opened in a browser. Changing the XML encoding to the ISO standard, resolves the problem, but we are concerned that the recipients of the XML will be unable to read it properly if the encoding is different. Currently our solution is to esacpe these characters like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
    <comments><![CDATA[Hola. Mi nombre es Pat. &#191;C&#243;mo puedo ayudarle?]]></comments>
</example>
```

My questions is, is this the correct way to go about escaping these characters?

Comment: I'd say the problem isn't with XML; it's with the way you use your editor or your browser (or both).

Comment: Why don't you encode the CDATA as UTF-8? This would be the „right” solution, IMHO.

Comment: Which browser(s) give an error on your first example? IMHO it should be correct. Otherwise the XML encoding specification in the head would not make any sense.

Comment: @Robert All of them, chrome, safari, and firefox (IE just kind of ignores it all together).

Comment: @ckruse We do have that section wrapped in CDATA tags, is there a way to specify an encoding directly on the CDATA element?

Comment: (Tangential comment: either all characters are international, or none of them are. To my mind, `¿Cómo` seems rather Spanish, while `Pat` seems rather international.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you write that Javascript is generating XML with an encoding set to UTF-8. How do you do this?

Did you check that the resulting file is really UTF-8 encoded? I kind of doubt it - if it was you would not have any trouble, right? My guess is that you specify the encoding in the XML file as encoding="UTF-8" but the files encoding is not really utf-8.

Best,
Ronald

Comment: I think you are right, in that the way I'm inspecting the file after the javascript has generated the XML is converting it to flat text, that in turn is not encoded to UTF-8